# Standardizing standardized data?

Tags: regression, spss, standardization, amos

Let's assume I standardize my data in SPSS through converting them to z-values. Then I save my dataset and load it into AMOS to do some regressions. Now, the data is already standardized, but AMOS will give me two sets of regression coefficients, labeled as standardized and unstandardized.

Does this mean that the unstandardized values in the output already are standardized? What is the meaning of standardized regression coefficients calculated based on already standardized data?

Comment: Do these two sets of coefficients differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the data, and indeed - if you standardize your data and then extract both unstandardized and standardized regression coefficients, they will be exactly the same. It seems that once you have transformed your data so that the mean is 0 and the variance is 1, further applications of this transformation does not change your data further.

Comment: Of course, you could say that standarization is an idempotent operation!